# Base64 - Encoding and Decoding

Tags: image, image-processing, encoding, decoding

### I am converting my image into Base64 on the android client

**What i have tried** ::

- I googled for Base64 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
- But i couldn't understand it much clearly

**My Questions**::

- `Base64` is this a image format like `JPG` & `PNG` ?
- Or `Base64` is just a `encoding/decoding` scheme ?
- If `Base64` is just a `encoding/decoding` scheme, what format the image
  will be when JPG is `Base64` encoded. i mean will it it be `JPG format`
  still and just `encoded as Base64` ?
- What relationship exists between `Base64`,`JPG`,`PNG` ?
- Also if the `strings` are `Base64 encoded` what format should we need to
  `decode` it to be human readable

**Hope i am clear with my question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 is a encoding/decoding scheme as stated in your [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
You can convert Bytes into Base64 String representation, this allows you to Save e.g. an Image as a (Base64) String.
The Format of the Data doesn´t matter at all (you can convert jpg, png, gif...),
this means you encode Bytes to a String and then if you decode this String you get exactly the same Bytes as before (same format).

A workflow would be:

- Create an Image
- Save Image as JPG
- Encode JPG Image as Base64 String
- Stream the String over some Network
- Decode Image from Base64 String on the receiver side
- show Image

Why do we encode at all? Because Strings are easier to use in HTML, Email and so on.

**Example:**
This is an Example of Base64 Encoding and Decoding using Python. It loads an Image, Encodes it, Decodes it and than saves the Data as an Image.

```
import base64

# load image and encode
jpgBase64String = base64.encodestring(open("test.jpg", "rb").read())

# work with jpgBase64String (e.g. send over Network)
[...]

# decode
image = base64.decodestring(newjpgtxt))

# write to File
f = open("test2.jpg", "w")
f.write(image)
f.close()
```

Comment: [+1] for good information ..... So, Base64 string can be of format jpg,png gif ..etc ? ..... So if we encode a jpg image into Base-64 format ... what should we decode it back to ? .... similarly for string(text-data) ? .... can you add more details on this to your answer !

Comment: It is already in the Answer: "The Format of the Data doesn´t matter at all".To clarify: You encode Bytes to a String. If you decode them you get exactly the same Bytes as before (same format).

Comment: I added Example Code to further clarify the use of base64

Answer (score -3):

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            success = False
            form=DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            print(form , "0000000000000")
            if form.is_valid():
                form = form.save(commit=False)
                filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
                src_image = request.POST.get('src_image')
                img_data = request.POST.get('img_src_path')
                gur_data = img_data.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64', ' ')
                data = gur_data.replace('  ', '+')
                imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
                filename = './media/src_image/' + filename + '.jpeg'
                print(filename , "222222222222222222")
                form.src_image = src_image
                form.img_src_path = filename
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(imgdata)
                form.save()
                saved = True
                success = True
                ref_image = request.POST.get('ref_image', '')
                ref_image_1 = ref_image
                ref_image_2 = str(BASE_DIR) + '/' + str(ref_image)
                result = str(uuid.uuid4())
                download_mat = str(result)
                save_path = str('static/out/') + download_mat + '.jpg'
                print(save_path, 'result path')
                add_with_front_panel(filename, ref_image_2, save_path)
    return render(request, 'demo.html', locals())
```

Comment: this does not answer the question.